# Setting an int as a specific bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

This might be a bit strange but this is the problem I'm having.

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct smallStruct{
    unsigned int First10 : 10;
    unsigned int Next10 : 10;
    unsigned int Third10 : 10;
    unsigned int extra : 1;
} small
```

I need to be able to pass in an int and set it so that it fits inside that 10 bits for First10, then another int for Next10, etc. The reason why this is the case is because I need to be able to store 4 different pieces of information inside a 4 byte variable, and this is the most efficient way I can think of to do this.

Would I need to do bit shifting for this?

Comment: Yes, you should do bit shifting for this.

Comment: What does "passing in an `int` mean? You mean as function parameter?

Comment: A bitfield-struct does not guarantee packing. And it does not gurantee a specific layout either. If you need a 32 bit variable, use `uin32_t` and bit-ops.

Comment: worth reading http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: @NayukiMinase: How would I use bitshift to achieve this? @ Kerrek: yes, that's what I think I would have to use, passing an int as a function parameter which changes the small's First10/etc

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign values; the bitfield logic takes care of the necessary modifications:

```
small make_small(int a, int b, int c) {
  small result = { a, b, c, 0 };
  return result;
}

void update_first(int value, small * s) {
  s->First10 = value;
}

// etc.
```